Representation of the lie algebra of the orthogonal group acting on symmetric matrices by conjugation
If we consider the action $\rho$ of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ on the real symmetric matrices $S_n$ resulting from conjugation, i.e.
$$\forall g \in O(n), \rho(g):S_n \rightarrow S_n, X \mapsto gXg^{-1},$$
then we get a representation of $O(n)$ as $(\rho, S_n)$.
If we look at the Lie algebra of $O(n)$, denoted by $\mathfrak{o}(n)$, my understanding is that we can get a representation of $\mathfrak{o}(n)$, written $(\rho', S_n)$, from our representation of $O(n)$.
My question is, for $a \in \mathfrak{o}(n)$, what does the endomorphism $\rho'(a) : S_n \rightarrow S_n$ look like?

The derivative of conjugation in a matrix group is the commutator so simply $\rho'(a)(X) = [a,X] = aX - Xa$.
You can see this by considering, for example
$$\begin{align}
\rho'(a)(X) &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\rho(\exp(ta))(X) \\
&= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\exp(ta)X\exp(-ta) \\
&= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} X + t[a,X] + \frac{t^2}{2}[a,[a,X]] + \dotsm \\
&= [a,X].
\end{align}$$

Thank you for your answer. In this case, the $\mathfrak{o}(n)$ would be the set of skew-symmetric matrices, right? What if we look at a Lie subgroup of the orthogonal matrices instead, do we obtain the corresponding Lie algebra by taking all the skew-symmetric matrices whose matrix exponential is in that subgroup?

@Kevlar Close, we take the set of all $a$ such that $\exp(ta)$ is in the subgroup for all $t$. If we only assume $\exp(a)$ is in the subgroup we run into problems. For example there can be nonzero elements with $\exp(a) = e$ which is in every subgroup but $a$ is not in every subalgebra. And yes we are assuming $\mathfrak{o}(n)$ is the skew-symmetric matrices (but only because you are considering the action on symmetric matrices - what I have said works for other realisations of $\mathfrak{o}(n)$ inside $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ as well)

Callum's answer applies to the fundamental vector representation of any matrix Lie group. It is presented in many if not most sources and is actually the inspiration for the Lie algebra concept historically.
But suppose you wanted something more specific and satisfying in this particular case. We can get hands-on with the exterior square $\Lambda^2V$ and symmetric square $S^2V$.

$\blacktriangleright$ We have an isomorphism $\mathfrak{so}(V)\cong\Lambda^2V$, where $V$ is a real inner product space.
Assuming $\|\mathbf{u}\wedge\mathbf{v}\|=\det(\mathbf{u}\,\mathbf{v})=1$ wlog (e.g. if $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\}$ is orthonormal), then $\mathbf{u}\wedge\mathbf{v}\in\Lambda^2V$ acts as a $90^\circ$ rotation in the oriented $\mathbf{uv}$-plane and annihilates the orthogonal complement. In the corresponding one-parameter subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(V)$ the rotation $\exp(\theta\,\mathbf{u}\wedge\mathbf{v})$ acts as a rotation by $\theta$ in the oriented $\mathbf{uv}$-plane and pointwise fixes its orthogonal complement.
Writing $\mathbf{u}^\ast$ for the adjoint a.k.a. dual vector, i.e. $\mathbf{u}^\ast(\mathbf{v})=\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle$, we get the action
$$(\mathbf{u}\wedge\mathbf{v})\mathbf{x} \,=\, (\mathbf{vu}^\ast-\mathbf{uv}^\ast)\mathbf{x} \,=\, \langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{x}\rangle\mathbf{v}-\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}\rangle\mathbf{u}.$$
This is evident when $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\}$ is orthonormal, and follows for $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\}$ L.I. (i.e. $\mathbf{u}\wedge\mathbf{v}\ne0$) by antisymmetry.
In fact the isomorphism $\mathfrak{so}(V)\cong\Lambda^2V$ is isometric. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(V)$ inherits the normalized Frobenius inner product $\langle A,B\rangle_F=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(A^\ast B)$ from ${\rm End}(V)$ (note $A^\ast=A^T$ for matrices), which is the Killing form $\kappa(A,B)$ up to scaling IIRC. Meanwhile $\Lambda^2V$ inherits the inner product from $V\otimes V$, which is effectively a polarization of the Gramian determinant.
The simple elements $\mathbf{u}\wedge\mathbf{v}$ span $\mathfrak{so}(V)$. Indeed, if $\{\mathbf{e}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{e}_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then
$$\{\mathbf{e}_i\wedge\mathbf{e}_j\mid 1\le i<j\le n\}$$
is a basis for $\Lambda^2V$. Moreover, the basis for $V$ is orthonormal iff the induced basis for $\Lambda^2V$ is too.
The real Spectral Theorem implies every element of $\mathfrak{so}(V)$ is expressible as
$$\mathbf{u}_1\wedge\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+\mathbf{u}_k\wedge\mathbf{v}_k$$
where $2k\le n$ and the 2D planes ${\rm span}\{{\bf u}_1,{\bf v}_1\},\cdots,{\rm span}\{{\bf u}_k,{\bf v}_k\}$ are orthogonal.
Equivalently, every element of $\mathfrak{so}(V)$ is expressible as
$$\lambda_1(\mathbf{u}_1\wedge\mathbf{v}_1)+\cdots+\lambda_k(\mathbf{u}_k\wedge\mathbf{v}_k)$$
where $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k>0$ and $\{{\bf u}_1,{\bf v}_1,\cdots,{\bf u}_k,{\bf v}_k\}$ is orthonormal.

$\blacktriangleright$ We have an isomorphism between the space of symmetric matrices and $S^2V$. The correspondence is via symmetrization, $\mathbf{uv}\leftrightarrow\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{uv}^\ast+\mathbf{vu}^\ast)$ (note $\mathbf{u}^\ast=\mathbf{u}^T$ for row and column vectors).
In fact, this isomorphsim is also isometric, using the normalized Frobenius inner product and inherited tensor inner product again. Every element of $S^2V$ is expressible as a sum of simple elements $\mathbf{xy}$. Moreover, a basis $\{{\bf e}_i\}$ for $V$ induces a basis $\{{\bf e}_i{\bf e}_j\mid 1\le i\le j\le n\}$ for $S^2V$. The basis for $V$ is orthonormal iff the one for $S^2V$ is.
The induced action of ${\rm GL}(V)$ is $A(\mathbf{xy})=(A\mathbf{x})(A\mathbf{y})$, and the restricted action of ${\rm O}(V)$ preserves $\Lambda^2V$'s inner product. Letting $A(t)$ parameterize a differentiable path in $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ with $A(0)=I$ and $A'(0)=W$, differentiating with the product and evaluating at $t=0$ yields the derivation property $$W(\mathbf{xy})=(W\mathbf{x})\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}(W\mathbf{y}) ~\textrm{ for }~ W\in{\rm End}(V),~\mathbf{xy}\in S^2V. \tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields
$$ (\mathbf{u}\wedge\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{xy})=(({\bf u}\wedge{\bf v}){\bf x}){\bf y}+{\bf x}(({\bf u}\wedge{\bf v}){\bf y}) $$
$$ =\langle{\bf u},{\bf x}\rangle{\bf vy}-\langle{\bf v},{\bf x}\rangle{\bf uy}+\langle{\bf u},{\bf y}\rangle{\bf xv}-\langle{\bf v},{\bf y}\rangle{\bf xu} $$
